# MATLAB - Repeat row n times (from A=[1;2;3] create B=[1;2;3;1;2;3;1;2;3])

Tags: matlab

I would like to create, from the column matrix A=[1;2;3], another column matrix that repeats A n times. For example, being n=3, the new matrix would be B=[1;2;3;1;2;3;1;2;3]. Is there a way to to that (preferably without using loops)?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`repmat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) it is a fantastic function:

```
repmat(A,[n,1])
```

The first value of the second parameter is repetitions in the first dimension (columns), the second in the second dimension (rows) etc.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it:

```
A2=A(:,ones(1,n));
B=A2(:)
```

Comment: This does replicate the vector `A` but not in the desired direction of the OP.

Comment: I didn't noticed the column result. so i added  some hack in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to do using `padarray`.

```
a = [1 2 3]
b = padarray(a, [2 0], 'post', 'circular')
```

`post` means add to the end of the array, `circular` pads with circular repetition of elements.